# How can I bypass the WSO2 IS sign in page?

Tags: javascript, wso2

So right now, a user can log into the website 'A' and when they're looking at their data they must login into 'B' (B being the WSO2 IS) to see it. I'm trying to figure out a way so that if the user is logged in, then they don't need to sign in for B. 
I want to implement it so that they can automatically sign into B if they're logged into A.

Is there a way to configure this through the WSO2 console or is there a script I have to implement? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use request path authentication with WSO2 IS. A request path authenticator is a special type of local authenticator meant to authenticate requests that contain the user’s credentials. This means that you can use the Single-Sign-On mechanism without having an identity provider login page to prompt the end user for credentials. Please refer [1] for more information regarding this.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Request+Path+Authentication